# My hair is too dry and knotted

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, adjectives

My hair is too dry and ***knotted.***

My hair is too dry and ***tangled.***

Which word is more commonly used? 
Knotted or tangled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tangled** is the idiomatic term for hair with a lot of "knots" in it.

While hair that is **tangled** can, correctly and technically, be described as **knotted**, be aware that **knotted** can be ambiguous, because there are [hair styles called "knots"](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+put+hair+up+in+knot&tbm=isch) (in English-speaking cultures, knotting the hair is a feminine style, which is why all these photos are of women's heads, but in other cultures, its something men do, [e.g.](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+wrap+a+sikh+turban&client=safari&tbm=isch)).  The sentence

> Her hair was **knotted** at the nape of her neck.

means she's [wearing a low bun](http://media.theknot.com/ImageStage/Objects/0019/0025393/large_image.jpg), not that she's unkempt.  (Hmm! Google Image search informs me some fashionistas [have not gotten the disambiguation memo](http://dirtylooks.com/blog/summer-hair-knotted-updos).)

Comment: Your cited example is perfectly clear in context, but the connotations between ***knotted*** and *tangled, matted, unkempt* are so strong that I think most native speakers would express it as *"Her hair was **tied in a knot** at the nape of her neck."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this might be gendered.  Men (those not hairstylists or otherwise ignorant of the lingo of doing hair) might use that expression in ignorance, but people who actually use that hairstyle (women) don't use the verb "tied" for it.  "Put up in a knot" or simply "up in a knot" is the usual expression for it, I think. (I defer to anybody in the hair-care industry.)

Comment: You could well be right regarding explicitly *verb* usage of "tie", particularly if we're talking about standard terminology within the tonsorial profession. All I'm saying is that ***knotted*** as a past tense/adjectival usage probably has too many negative connotations to be a likely choice for deliberately-created hairstyles involving "knots".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are severely mistaken.  [Here's the first page of results from Google's N-gram on "hair knotted" 1984-2000, **ALL** of which refer to the hair style](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hair%20knotted%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1984,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en).  It **is** the idiom for that.

Comment: I'm not convinced that link has much relevance to OP's *"My hair is knotted"* context, and it's worth noting that ["hair tied" is far more common than "hair knotted"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hair+tied%2Chair+knotted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chair%20tied%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chair%20knotted%3B%2Cc0). But my underlying substantive point is simply that *dry and knotted hair* doesn't make me think of hair deliberately styled into a knot - it's just an alternative to *tangled* in that context.

Comment: \*heavy sigh of exasperation.\* @FumbleFingers, yes, hair is **tied** into pony tails and similar arrangements, but **knotted** or **put up** into buns.  The fact that you don't have this association while **fifty percent of the population does**, is identical to an American English speaker insisting "cricket" can't be a verb.

Comment: Ah well, it's another day. Having slept on it, and having now seen more references to *knotted hair* in the last 24 hours than probably the whole of my life before, I guess I must concede that I was simply mistaken on this one. I'll leave my comments and answer, because that *was* how I saw things, but I fully accept that you can use all variants of ***knot*** in relation to hair without necessarily implying *tangled, unkempt, dirty*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine, but idiomatically [*tangled*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22piggey%22%20%22voice%20in%20the%20wilderness%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22tangled%20greasy%20hair%22&tbm=bks) is much more common than [***knotted*** hair](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22piggey%22%20%22voice%20in%20the%20wilderness%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22knotted%20greasy%20hair%22&tbm=bks). I searched Google Books for ***greasy*** there because it's more of a "stock image" for unkempt dirty hair. But you could say if OP wants ***dry*** it's better to go for ***knotted*** to keep as far away from the clichéed stereotype as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

- *I have long thick hair which often **gets tangles**, especially after I've washed it*.

  Generally speaking, the strands of hair are not straight, so when I brush my hair I have to tug at it. By tugging gently, the tangled hair will straighten.
- ***Knots** usually occur when hair is very damaged, dry and brittle, this is more difficult to **untangle***.

  Literally some of the ends are knotted, it may look like a small ball and depending on the severity, it might need to be cut. If there are a lot of knots in the hair, you could say
- *My hair is knotted*

  But without proper context, the phrase could be interpreted to mean a particular hairstyle

[image: Sleek-knotted-hair]
Sleek-knotted-hair

When there are several difficult knots and hair looks very unkempt we speak about ***[matted hair](http://tangledhairtechs.blogspot.it/2013/07/how-to-detangle-dry-matted-hair-without.html)***

- My small daughter hates having her hair brushed, she cries when I untangle her knots.
- She had left her hair extensions in for an entire year, no wonder it became ***matted***.